# How do I get an image from the folder my .class file is in? No .bin or anything. Please just the folder the .class file is in

Tags: java, imageicon, getresource

I am trying to run this code (Ignore the paimon bit):

```
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class optionpanes {

        public static void main(String Args[]){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(optionpanes.class.getResource("Paimon_1.png"));
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Can I have that?", "Hungry Paimon", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, null, 0);
        }
    }
```

but I only get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:217)
at optionpanes.main(optionpanes.java:23)

My project is D:\Java\GUI\Optionpanes

Is there a different more reliable way to get the image because I've been seeing .getResource a lot but it really isn't helping me

Comment: Can you please post the complete error and where exactly did you place the file `Paimon_1.png`?

Comment: I placed Paimon_1.png inside D:\Java\GUI\Optionpanes. This is the same folder where the optionpanes.class file is in

Comment: You need to place it in resources folder. See this https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read the content of a file in Java.
What your code tries to do, is find the file in a specific folder called the `resources` folder. It is a specified folder where the, well... Resources are. And that is exactly what you have there.

A static image should be part of this folder. If you are using an IDE, just put the image in the `resources` folder and try to read it the same way.

If you want to read it in a specific place in the drive (not recommended since when you create a `.jar` file, or delete the image file, it will not be accessible).

Use this way:

```java
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\Java\\GUI\\Optionpanes\\Paimon_1.png");
```